# Transform 3-component Android Rotation Vector to (4-component) quaternion

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

I am trying to implement the following application:

I stream the 3-component Android Rotation Vector of my smartphone to my computer, where an object is shown in Unity and shall be rotated according to the rotation of my smartphone.

How can I transform the 3-component Android Rotation Vector into a quaternion for use in a 3D application, e.g., in Unity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Android Rotation Vector is either made up of three or of four components (because one is redundant!).
I will describe how to define a quaternion given the 3-component representation of the Android Rotation Vector.

The three elements of the rotation vector are equal to the *last three components of a unit quaternion:

```
< q0, q1, q2, q3 > = < (θ/2), xsin(θ/2), ysin(θ/2), z*sin(θ/2) >
```

Because it is a *unit* quaternion (its length equals 1), we can infer the first quaternion value `q0` from the remaining three.

We know

```
1 = |q| = sqrt( q0^2 + q1^2 + q2^2 + q3^2 )
```

which we can transform into

```
q0 = sqrt( 1 - q1^2 - q2^2 - q3^2 )
```

Voilà, there we have it. The fourth quaternion component `q0`.